# Where is the Intel Common Redundant Power Supply (CRPS) Standard Specified?

Tags: power-supply, standard, intel

Intel server reference designs use the Intel Common Redundant Power Supply Standard (CRPS).  These documents include a brief over view of CRPS with information like the pin names and refer the reader to the CRPS specification document for more details.  I've googled for the mentioned CRPS specification document but haven't been able to find it.  CRPS compatible power supplies are offered by numerous manufactures so the info must be out there some place.

What document / standard / specification details the CRPS standard?

Comment: The best person to ask would probably be intel

Comment: Agree - their website may have it , but you may have to be a « member » ie paid for info or a registered developer...

Comment: Agreed. Your asking for proprietary info that you will have to pay Intel for. In return Intel will demand security protocols from you.

Comment: Are you saying you know that CRPS is a proprietary standard?  I was under the impression it was supposed to be an open standard much like ATX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Open Compute Project](https://www.opencompute.org/) has published the specification *Modular Hardware System-Common Redundant Power Supply* (M-CRPS). The version 1.00 Release Candidate 4 was published November 1st, 2022 - it can be found [here](https://www.opencompute.org/documents/m-crps-r1-v1p0-rc4-pdf).

It has been contributed to by Intel (among others). However exact relations to the earlier Common Redundant Power Supply Standard (CRPS) by Intel is a bit unclear. So be aware that there may be some differences.